# Editar un registro mediante un form (ajax, codeigniter)

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, formularios

tengo en mi tabla llenada mediante una consulta y un `foreach` en esta tabla despues de llenarla con registros, tengo un boton para editar el cual abre un modal y desde ahi editar el registro.

el problema es que al abrir el modal no carga los input con los datos de ese registro y muestran este error **Message: Trying to get property of non-object**.

esta es mi consulta para llenar la tabla

```
public function lineas4() { 

    $this->db->order_by('depto', 'asc');
    $this->db->order_by('nombre', 'asc');
    // $this->db->where('depto', 422);
    $query_lineas4=$this->db->get('lineas');

    if ( $query_lineas4->num_rows > 0 ) {
        return $query_lineas4->result();
    }
    return false;
}
```

El boton de editar que aparece en la tabla:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs editar" title="Editar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"> Editar</span></a>
```

la funcion que dispara el boton de editar:

```
function getEditarLinea(){
    var id_linea = $('#id_linea').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?=base_url('departamentos/getEditarLinea')?>",
        type: 'post',
        data: {id : id_linea},
        contentType:false,
        dataType:false,
        processData:false,
        success: function (respuesta){
            $("#myModalEditar").modal('show');
            $("#frmEditar").empty().append(respuesta);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

la funcion en el controlador:

```
public function getEditarLinea(){
    $data['query'] = $this->modelo->getEditar();
    $this->load->view('departamentos/lin_form_editar', $data);
}
```

la funcion con la consulta en el modelo que traera el registro cuando sea igual al id seleccionado:

```
public function getEditar(){
    // var_dump($this->input->post('id'));
    $this->db->where('id_linea', $this->input->post('id'));
    $query=$this->db->get('lineas');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        return $query->row();
    }
    return false;
}
```

el modal que carga el controlador:

```
<?php $row = $query;
```

var_dump($row);
?>

×
            Editar Linea de Producción

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="depto" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Departamento</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="depto" id="depto" class="form-control" value="<?=$row->depto?>" placeholder="Departamento">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" value="<?=$row->nombre?>" placeholder="Nombre">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="codigo" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Código</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" class="form-control" value="<?=$row->codigo?>" placeholder="Código">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- <div class="form-group"> 
            <label for="descripcion" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Tipo de Documento</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" class="form-control" value="<?=$row->descripcion?>" placeholder="Nombre del Departamento">
            </div>
        </div>-->



    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="<?=$row->id_linea?>" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button id="btnEditarLinea"  class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```

Gracias por su tiempo, colegas.

Comment: hola, en que momento mandas llamar esta función `getEditarLinea()` tendira que ser algo asi `<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs editar" onclick="getEditarLinea(<?= $info->id?>)"` y en el js `getEditarLinea(id_linea){... data: {id : id_linea},}`

Comment: la manera en la que mando a llama la funcion es similar: 

` <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs editar" title="Editar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"> Editar</span></a>`

y en mi script :
` $(".editar").on("click", getEditarLinea);`

Comment: pero en que momento le mandas el id seleccionado con el `click`

Comment: en la funcion getEditarLinea..... `function getEditarLinea(){
    var id_linea = $('#id_linea').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?=base_url('departamentos/getEditarLinea')?>",
        type: 'post',
        data: {id : id_linea},
        contentType:false,
        dataType:false,
        processData:false,
        success: function (respuesta){
            $("#myModalEditar").modal('show');
            $("#frmEditar").empty().append(respuesta);
        }
    });
    return false;
}`

justo en esta parte `var id_linea = $('#id_linea').val();`